# Added Additional IP Address to Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS7 stopped responding

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I've previously added two IP addresses to a Windows 2008 R2 server and it's worked fine but when I add another one to the Network Adaptor IIS stops serving any of the existing websites.  Resetting IIS or restarting the server doesn't fix it.

I've tried turning off Windows Firewall and checked the Event Log but there's nothing relevant.

Any suggestions on how I can fix or debug this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you access other services on the machine when this happens? Are you sure the IP you are attempting to add is not your gateway or broadcast address?

Comment: Did you specify in IIS which IP address applies to each website?

Comment: Yes, I can FTP, RDP to the server while this is happening and each website has bindings for IP address/domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Finally sorted this now.  Turned out after I added the IP address then reset IIS, when the website tried to connect to the database server, it tried to connect from the last IP address added which was blocked by the DB server's firewall.

Someone had added a 240 second timeout to the connection string so it appeared that IIS wasn't responding when it was actually just trying for 4 minutes to connect before timing out.

Adding the new IP to the DB server's firewall fixed the problem and I've reduced that connection string timeout!

Sorry and thanks for your help devicenull & murisonc.